# Eloquent Javascript FizzBuzz

Tags: javascript

I'm currently working through eloquent javascript.

I'm trying to do the fizzbuzz task, I'm struggling when having to print numbers divisible by 3 & 5.

Task and my solution so far below.

Cheers.

**Task:**

Write a program that uses console.log to print all the numbers from 1
to 100, with two exceptions. For numbers divisible by 3, print "Fizz"
instead of the number, and for numbers divisible by 5 (and not 3), print
"Buzz" instead.
When you have that working, modify your program to print "FizzBuzz",
for numbers that are divisible by both 3 and 5 (and still print "Fizz" or
"Buzz" for numbers divisible by only one of those).
(This is actually an interview question that has be

**My solution:**

```
for(i=1; i<101; i++) {
    if(i % 3 === 0) {
        console.log("Fizz");
    } else if(i % 5 === 0) {
        console.log("Buzz");
    } else if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0){
        console.log("FizzBuzz");
    } else {
        console.log("What should this be?");
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FizzBuzz program(details given) in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16620665/fizzbuzz-programdetails-given-in-javascript)

Comment: The origin of this problem: [Using FizzBuzz to Find Developers who Grok Coding](https://imranontech.com/2007/01/24/using-fizzbuzz-to-find-developers-who-grok-coding/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code would never reach the block inside `else if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0)` because either `if (i % 3 === 0)` or `else if (i % 5 === 0)` would be true first.

Here's maybe an easier way to think about this problem:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    var message = "";
    if (i % 3 === 0) {
        message = "Fizz"
    } 
    if (i % 5 === 0) {
        message += "Buzz";
    } 
    console.log(message || i);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why in the book and here this answer is preferred to the one for(i=1; i<101; i++) {
    if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0){
        console.log("FizzBuzz");
    } else if(i % 3 === 0) {
        console.log("Fizz");
    } else if(i % 5 === 0) {
        console.log("Buzz");
    } else {
        console.log("What should this be?");
    }
}

Answer (score 3):

**NOTE**: *please* don't do this in production code!

You could even do it with an ES6 one-liner (broken on multple lines for "clarity").

```js
console.log(
  [...Array(100).keys()].map((_, i) => i + 1)
                        .map(
                            i => (
                                    (i % 3 === 0 ? "Fizz" : "")
                                  + (i % 5 === 0 ? "Buzz" : "")
                                 ) || i
                        )
                        .join("\n")
);
```

here is the break-down of the various parts:

```
[...Array(100).keys()]
```

creates an empty array of length 100, and returns its keys, which are then used to build a new array, so we get `[0 ... 99]`

```
.map((_, i) => i + 1)
```

this replaces each element with its index incremented by 1, so we now have `[1 ... 100]`

```
.map(i => ...)
```

now we apply FizzBuzz logic, by testing all the possible combinations in the correct order, using the ternary operator

```
.join("\n");
```

and finally we join the result as a single string separated with newlines.

Comment: I like this ES6 way rather than using for-statement.

Comment: Only do this if you really don't like the next developer to read your code... :S

Comment: @grayedfox yeah I'd never recommend that in production code!

Comment: I would recommend it for production code, once optimized a bit further: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40447869/eloquent-javascript-fizzbuzz/71615746#71615746

Answer (score 2):

Your conditions were in the wrong order:

```
for(i=1; i<101; i++) {
    if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0){
        console.log("FizzBuzz");
    } else if(i % 3 === 0) {
        console.log("Fizz");
    } else if(i % 5 === 0) {
        console.log("Buzz");
    } else {
        console.log("What should this be?");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**03-26-2022**

New answer based on idea provided by [Danny '365CSI' Engelman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71615746/25197).
His version was indeed faster but a combo of his array fill method and my early return function [beats us both](https://jsben.ch/oR3KQ) (at least in Chrome).

```js
const fizzBuzz = (n) => {
  if (n % 15 === 0) return 'FizzBuzz';
  if (n % 3 === 0) return 'Fizz';
  if (n % 5 === 0) return 'Buzz';
  return n;
};

const arr = Array(100)
  .fill(fizzBuzz)
  .map((func, i) => func(i + 1));

console.log(arr.join(', '));
```

*Old Answer*

Succinct, functional & fast. I'm not sure it gets more eloquent than this.

```js
const oneToOneHundred = Array.from({ length: 100 }, (_, i) => i + 1);

const fizzBuzz = (n) => {
  if (n % 15 === 0) return 'FizzBuzz';
  if (n % 3 === 0) return 'Fizz';
  if (n % 5 === 0) return 'Buzz';
  return n;
};

const arr = oneToOneHundred.map((i) => fizzBuzz(i));

console.log(arr.join(', '));
```

Comment: Maybe... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40447869/eloquent-javascript-fizzbuzz/71615746#71615746

Comment: Cool. I like it! Updated this answer with of yours and a bit of mine after doing some speed testing.

Comment: The inevitable _speed_ over _maintainability_; when **Buzz** needs to be renamed to **Bazz**, or a third **%7 for "Bazz"** needs to be added, your code gets more complex.

Comment:  _Houston, we have a problem._  When you run your new version trough Terser, the function is minified and used as inline function. Run the benchmark multiple times: https://jsben.ch/VdkEX The Minified version will, ever so often, drop to 95% "Performance"

Comment: You kept me busy for the better part of the day.... strict comparison is lost when Minifiers are applied. And I foremost did not like the "Fizz" and "Buzz" repetition in your version.  Performance tests are not 100% correct, see  https://jsben.ch/fzA57 run this test 10 times, and they are all different - My **Parameters** version tops yours ever so often. The **Filled Object** version is a fascinating observation

Comment: Yeah. It's fun playing around with this stuff sometimes. Interesting to see how different browsers (I generally use Firefox) can handle things differently. The biggest win for speed here seems to be the .fill(). No one had done it that way until your answer. Also, you're right. For consistent performance the inline function stays consistent vs having the calculation as a separate function. I would have guessed the opposite. Anyway... fun stuff! Cheers. 

Answer (score 1):

```js
let arr = Array(100)
  .fill((x, div, label) => x % div ? "" : label) //store Function in every index
  .map((func, idx) =>
    func(++idx, 3, "Fizz") + func(idx, 5, "Buzz") || idx
  );
document.body.append(arr.join(", "));
```

`fill` takes a **single** Object, it is not executed 100 times!
Since JavaScript Functions are Objects this code **declares** a function **once**

Note the `++idx` because we want to start at 1, not 0

In JavaScript `""+""` is a Falsy value, thus it returns the `idx` value for non-FizzBuzz numbers

More Array Methods explained: https://array-methods.github.io

## Update

- maintainable
- extendible
- translatable
- performant

```js
let arr = Array(100)
  .fill( { three: "Fizz", five: "Buzz" })
  .map(( { three,five }, idx) => {
    idx++;
    if (idx % 15 == 0) return three + five;
    if (idx % 3 == 0) return three;
    if (idx % 5 == 0) return five;
    return idx;
  });
console.log(arr.join(", "));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

```
for(i=1; i<101; i++) {
    if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0){
        console.log("FizzBuzz");
    };
    if(i % 3 === 0) {
        console.log("Fizz");
    } else if(i % 5 === 0) {
        console.log("Buzz");
    } else {
    console.log(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: I doesn't work properly, for numbers divisible by 3 and 5 it prints `FizzBuzz\nFizz` instead just `FizzBuzz`.

Comment: "(and still print "Fizz" or "Buzz" for numbers divisible by only one of those)" OP wants Fizz to print thats why it was made to print it.

Answer (score 0):

```html
for (i = 1; i < 101; i++) {
  var result = "";
  if (i % 3 === 0) { result += "Fizz";}
  if (i % 5 === 0) { result += "Buzz";}
  console.log(result || i);
}
```

- create a result variable
- append Fizz if it is even divisible by 3
- append Buzz if it is even divisible by 5
- if result === "" log i

  - otherwise log result
- result resets to "" at the start of each loop

Search for "fizzbuzz golf" to see the shortest solutions possible in a variety of languages.

Answer (score 0):

```
function PrintFizzBuzz(){

    for(i=1;i<=100;i++){
        if(i % 3 == 0 && i % 15 != 0)
        console.log("Fizz");
        else if(i % 5 == 0 && i % 15 != 0)
        console.log("Buzz");
        else if(i % 5 == 0 && i % 15 == 0)
        console.log("FizzBuzz");
        else
        console.log(i); 
    }
}
PrintFizzBuzz();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer:

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0 ) {
       console.log("FizzBuzz");
  }
    else if (i % 5 === 0){
       console.log("Buzz");
    }
    else if (i % 3 === 0){
       console.log("Fizz");
    }
    else {
    console.log(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solutions to FizzBuzz that append to an output string are eloquent but are a bit inflexible (e.g. if the problem is changed to require different outputs).

This solution avoids appending, and uses nested shorthand conditionals for brevity:

```
for(let i=1; i <= 100; i++){
  let str = 
    i%3 === 0 && i%5 === 0 ? "FizzBuzz" : 
      i%3 === 0 ? "Fizz" :      
        i%5 === 0 ? "Buzz" : 
          i;
  console.log(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var nums = [];
var index = 0;
var x = 0;
while(nums.length <= 100){
    nums.push(index);
    index++;
}
for(x;x < nums.length;x++){
    if(nums[x] % 5 == 0 && nums[x] % 3 != 0){
        
        nums[x] = "buzz";
    }
    if(nums[x] % 3 == 0 && nums[x] % 5 != 0){
        nums[x] = "fizz";

    }
    if(nums[x] % 5 == 0 && nums[x] % 5 == 0){
        nums[x] = "fizzbuzz";

    }
    console.log(nums[x]);
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>question</title>
        <script src="sketch.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (let i=1;i<=100; i++) {
    if ((i%5 === 0) && (i%3 === 0)) {
        console.log("FizzBuzz") }
    else if (i%3 === 0) {
        console.log("Fizz")}
    else if (i%5 === 0) {
        console.log("Buzz")}
    else { console.log(i) }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
for (i = 1; i < 101; i++) {
  if (i % (3 * 5) === 0) console.log('fizzbuzz');
  else if (i % 3 === 0) console.log('fizz');
  else if (i % 5 === 0) console.log('buzz');
  else console.log(i);
}
```

}